# How to calculate the average,maximum,minimum value from the data frame column in a single line with out renaming the columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, aws-databricks

How to calculate the average,maximum,minimum value of the same column from the data frame column in a single line with out renaming the columns using pyspark

I have used the below command but it was throwing an error

```
df5=df5.agg(avg(col("Salaray")),min(col("Salaray")),max(col("Salaray")))
```

Comment: What error do you see?

Answer (score 4):

##### Don't do this `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`

Some functions like `pyspark.sql.functions.min` and `pyspark.sql.functions.max` will mess up with built-in functions `min`, `max`, and would cause many weird issues later. Do this instead:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

##### Use `alias` if you want to rename column

```py
F.avg(F.col('salary')).alias('avg_salary')
```

##### The complete working code

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .agg(
        F.avg(F.col('salary')).alias('avg_salary'),
        F.min(F.col('salary')).alias('min_salary'),
        F.max(F.col('salary')).alias('max_salary'),
    )
    .show()
)
# +----------+----------+----------+
# |avg_salary|min_salary|max_salary|
# +----------+----------+----------+
# |     200.0|       100|       300|
# +----------+----------+----------+
```